# Merge tables with same headers but in different order in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have two tables in Excel with the same table headers but in different orders.

How can I merge the rows into 1 table but in such way that all the values are still in the correct column based on the column headers?

I am afraid I will have to use VBA, but I just wanted to make sure that there are not other clever options.

Maybe Excel is not even the best software to use for this task?

Comment: Just with Excel, this would need a formula like `INDEX(...MATCH(......MATCH(...)))` if you construct a new header and a column with "keys" that you take from both tables. And maybe a Remove Duplicates afterwards. I think that VBA would be longer to code for this. Do you have anything that could work like an ID/key in each table?

Comment: No I don't have an identifier/key. I just have two tables with the exact same column headers and different data

Comment: Ok, so if you can add a column with a simple numeric ID, that can still do the trick! Is that possible?

Comment: yes, so I should just add a column in each table with the numbers 1-n in both tables?

Comment: Yes that's it! And then add the both column and you'll have to do 2 formula! I posting an example! ;)

Comment: Glad it worked for you! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful about the use of `$`, you have to lock every thing with it, except :

- The row of the ID you test in the destination table
- The column of the Header you test in the destination table

That way, you'll be able to "extend" the formula on the whole row and until the last ID for that table.

Then do the same for the second table! Et voilà! ;)

---

For the 1st table :

```
=INDEX($B$2:$C$3;MATCH($I2;$A$2:$A$3;0);MATCH(J$1;$B$1:$C$1;0))
```

For the 2nd table :

```
=INDEX($B$2:$C$3;MATCH($I2;$A$2:$A$3;0);MATCH(J$1;$B$1:$C$1;0))
```

---

Screenshots (I'm on French version, so `EQUIV`=`MATCH` in English) :

1st Table:

[image]

2nd Table:

[image]